# Put two html elements horizontally by rule

Tags: html, css, devexpress

I want put textbox with button side by side.
But with next rules:

1) TextBox must fill all free width space of screen (leftpanel div)

2) Button have fixed width and height and must always stick to the right edge of browser. (rightpanel div)

My CSS style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.centerpanel {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .leftpanel {
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 90%;
        float: left
    }

    .rightpanel {
        background: blue;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 10%;
        float: left
    }
</style>
```

in full screen it works well. But if i make browser window shortly by dragging edge/corners button partially trimmed.

sample (near full screen):

[image]

sample (after dragging small screen):

[image]

what i want:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your layout,

**First `flexbox`**

```css
.flexwrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%:
}

.flexwrap input {
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=flexwrap>
  <input>
  <button>+</button>
</div>
```

**Second `table`**

```css
.tablewrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.tablewrap .t-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.tablewrap .t-cell input {
  width: 100%;
}
.tablewrap .t-cell:first-child{
  padding-right:20px;
}
.tablewrap .t-cell:last-child {
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class=tablewrap>
  <span class=t-cell>
    <input>
  </span>
  <span class=t-cell>
    <button>+</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, its very clear. But it's solution works on older browsers or only on freshes versions of (chrome/safari/opera)?

Comment: `Flexbox` works on [following browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can also use `table`, this will work on all browser, but I would recommend you to use `flexbox`.

Comment: cool, thank you. it indicates that i can use ie 8 and other older browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=table if customer make some niggles, i change it, but now i use flexbox!